# Java- Scanner is not reading String properly

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner, jgrasp

I am writing a program for a school project in which I read a `.csv` file and perform calculations based on the data within it.

```
System.out.println("Please enter a second data set to search:\nFor example, type 'narcotics, poss,' 'criminal damage,' or 'battery.'\nCapitalization does not matter.");
        secondDataSet = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Searching for instances of " + secondDataSet);
        if (!secondDataSet.equals(""))
        {
           while (inputStream.readLine() != null)
           {
              String[] all = line.split(splitBy);
              if (all[8].toUpperCase().equals("TRUE"))
              {
                 numArrests++;
              }
              if (all[8].toUpperCase().equals("FALSE"))
              {
                 numNonArrests++;
              }
              if (all[5].equals(secondDataSet))
              {
                 secondDataCount++;
              }
              numberOfLines++;
              line = inputStream.readLine();
           }
           if (secondDataCount == 0)
           {
              i--;
              System.out.println("The data set you entered does not exist.\nPlease try checking your spelling or reformatting your response.");
           }
```

The above is part of my code I am using that contains my `Scanner` problems. I am reading a `.csv` containing the Chicago arrest records for the past several years. Every time I run the program, however, it skips past the `scan.nextLine()`. It just executes my print statement "Please enter a second data set..." and then prints out "Searching for instances of   ".

I am using jGRASP, and my compiler looks like:

```
 Please enter a data set to search:
 For example, type 'narcotics, poss,' 'criminal damage,' or 'battery.'
 Capitalization does not matter.
 Searching for instances of
```

And it loops four times without getting user input. I tried using `scan.next()` instead, but that did not work when I input a String with two words because some there are some values in the `.csv` like "CRIMINAL DAMAGE" and `scan.next()` searched for the words "CRIMINAL" and "DAMAGE" separately. If someone has any suggestions on how to make the computer stop to read the `scan.nextLine()`, use `scan.next()` to read two words, or any other solution to this I would appreciate it.

I am extremely confused by this at the moment so any help would be very nice as I've spent an enormous amount of time on a small part of a large project that I need to complete... Also, I can clarify any questions you may have if my question is unclear or vague.

Comment: please post complete code

Comment: Most likely there are CRLF:s in the buffer (from the code that you *didn't* post), so it's processing them before waiting for new input.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded so quickly! I was just now able to fix the problem (after much frustration) by putting the "for" loop in my main method instead, though I don't fully understand how that solved the issue. I am on a tight time deadline so I will have to look into this more after I finish the program.